# How to replace any text in a column with a checkmark?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a checklist in Google Sheets to use as a template, to open a new copy for each client I work with. I already have conditional formatting so that if anything is entered into the mark column, it strikes out the task. I also want to have it so that anything inputted into the mark column is converted into a check mark, ✓. I don't know how to code, but I found this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.value == “/”) e.range.setValue(“✓”) // e.value is only set when a single cell was edited
}
```

I get an error about an illegal character on line 2. Obviously though it was the check, but it happens if I replace it with normal text.

Even if I didn't have this error, the code is incomplete. I'd need to tell the script to only watch a certain column. And right now it is only looking for a "/" value. I'm not sure how to change it so that it would go off any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the `“` and `”`, they need to be both `"`.

As for checking whether it's a certain column and any value you can replace the condition

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) e.range.setValue("✓");
}
```

Where you use 4 if it's supposed to be column D.

Comment: This works great! But one problem: I can't delete the checkmarks. The checks pop right back in.

Comment: Try adding to the condition `&& e.value !== ""` (cannot verify as I'm not on a computer).

Comment: Someone on another forum posted this, which works perfectly:

function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = 1;
  var firstRow = 4;
  var checkmark = '\u2713';

  // If the selected cell is...
  if (
    range.getColumn() == column // in the checkmark column
    && range.getRow() >= firstRow // below the header rows
    && e.value.length > 0 // not empty
    && e.value != checkmark // not already a checkmark
  ) {
    // ...replace it with a checkmark.
    range.setValue(checkmark);
  }
}